# GHCi and compiled code seem to behave differently

Tags: haskell, io

I have a very strange problem. The following code gives different results when compiled as compared to running in ghci,

```
main = do
  putStr "Please enter your name: "
  name <- getLine
  putStr ("Hello, " ++ name ++ ", how are you?")
```

When run it in ghci it does as one would expect,

```
Please enter your name: dglmoore
Hello, dglmoore, how are you?
```

However, when I compile the code to an executable it requires that I provide the input before any output is generated so I end up with this,

```
dglmoore
Please enter your name: Hello, dglmoore, how are you?
```

I've seen a similar problem before, but I cannot seem to find it again.

I am using ghc version 7.4.1 from the Haskell Platform version 2012.2.0.0.

Anyone have any idea why they give different results and how I can get both versions to do the "correct" thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a buffering issue. Usually IO is line buffered (i.e. the output doesn't actually show up on the screen until you print a new line or exceed the buffer size) unless you explicitly flush the buffer. In ghci it isn't, so the issue doesn't show up.

You can use `hFlush stdout` to flush stdout, causing the output to be printed to the screen, before you call `getLine`.

Alternatively you can use `hSetBuffering NoBuffering` to disable buffering altogether, removing the need for `hFlush`. That could have a negative impact on IO performance though.

Comment: Wow, I've been using Haskell for the better part of two years and have never come across the problem before. That worked like a charm.

Comment: @DougMoore Note that terminal output being line-buffered is the case in the majority of programming languages - not just Haskell (though in some languages reading input automatically causes the output to be flushed, removing this source of errors).